# Deploy a .NET Core Console app to PCF

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-core, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy a dotnet core Console app to PCF, it seems to deploy fine, but the health check fails trying to reach the app at `http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`. Since it's a console app, it doesn't have an HTTP endpoint. On the app info I can see this:

```
Start Command: dotnet dotnet-app.dll --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:${PORT}
```

It's expecting the app to be a web app by default. Is there a way to deploy it using a console app setup for pcf?

The buildpack is:

```
Buildpack: ASP.NET Core (buildpack-1.0.4)
```

I'm wondering if there is a pure .NET Core buildpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the health check in the manifest to `health-check-type: process` and that did the trick.

However, having a process health check in place adds some value when diagnosing problems but it's not ideal. Later on, talking with colleagues, they recommended hosting the app as a WepApi application so if the process hangs the http health check will detect it when trying to hit the endpoint.

Since WebApi applications are self-hosted in .net core, a better solution is to have a WebApi application doing everything your console app does and also hosting the health check endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the 'no-route' to your manifest file?

This will prevent pcf from trying to bind a port.

```
no-route: true
```

You may also need to disable health checking:

```
cf set-health-check APP_NAME none
```

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar first, I changed the health check in the manifest to `health-check-type: process` and that did the trick. Having a process health check in place adds some value when diagnosing problems but it's not ideal. Later on, talking with colleagues, they recommended hosting the app as a Wep.Api app so if the process hangs the http health check will detect it when trying to hit the endpoint. So basically the solution is to have an app doing everything your console app does and also hosting the health check endpoint.